# ClearFocus sets focus on the first view in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

When clearFocus() on a LinearLayout is called, it sets focus on the first view in the Linearlayout.  I am reading the android View document and it says

> Note: When not in touch-mode, the framework will try to give focus to the first focusable View from the top after focus is cleared. Hence, if this View is the first from the top that can take focus, then all callbacks related to clearing focus will be invoked after which the framework will give focus to this view.
>   [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus())

So, I checked IsInTouchMode on the LinearLayout before calling clearFocus, but IsInTouchMode  is true.

I am wondering what is affecting this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" so that focus will be first on parent layout and then on their child/s.

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

**Let me know if it worked or not.**

Comment: Hi Sumit, thank you very much for posting the answer, although setting it to "beforeDescendants", using the attribute solved my problem!!!  Setting the attribute to "blockDescendants" before calling ClearFocus and then set it back to "beforeDescendants" after fixed the issue. So, thank you!!